# Drupal 7 confirm_form putting title in breadcrumb

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a custom module that displays a list of users who registered for our hosts events. I added a delete link and the link takes them to the `confirm_form()` page. Works fine but it looks off, the question is showing up in the breadcrumb area. Any idea what is causing this?

```
return confirm_form(
  $form,
  t('Are you sure you want to delete this?'),
  '<front>',
  t('This action cannot be undone.'),
  t('Delete'),
  t('Cancel')
);
```

[image]

**Update:** I can get it working if I use my own form:

```
$form['id'] = array(
  '#type' => 'value',
  '#value' => $id,
 );

 $form['header'] = array
  (
  '#markup' => t('Are you sure you wish to delete?'),
  '#prefix' => '',
  '#suffix' => '',
 );
 $form['warning'] = array
 (
  '#markup' => t(' Warning, this action cannot be undone'),
  '#prefix' => '',
  '#suffix' => '',
   );
  $form['delete_button'] = array
  (
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Delete item'),
 );
 return $form;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the code that the [confirm_form() function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/confirm_form/7.x) contains, you will notice it calls `drupal_set_title($question)` which sets the page title.
You could just get around it by calling `drupal_set_title('something here')` after your call to confirm_form.

eg.

```
$cform = confirm_form(
  $form,
  t('Are you sure you want to delete this?'),
  '<front>',
  t('This action cannot be undone.'),
  t('Delete'),
  t('Cancel')
);
drupal_set_title('something');
return $cform;
```